# windows 10 copy file from one location takes a long time

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-transfer

Windows 10 open file explorer .
select a file in one directory.
right mouse and drag to move to another directory.
immediately click on the move to directory.
The copy functions hangs 'calculating' for maybe 30 seconds
and finally will copy/move

Comment: Is the destination on the same drive or a different one? Is the computer particularly old? Is the file large? Do you have antivirus software running that may be scanning the file?

Comment: disable Windows Defender and look if this makes it faster

Comment: small file , new computer 64 bit. Windows defender is running. will disable and try again.

Comment: is it faster without defender?